# Multi-site Subfolder Nginx Configuration

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have Nginx server. Currently, I have two projects:

1. www.xyz.com -> /var/www/project/public; (This is working)
2. www.xyz.com/blog -> /var/www/blog; (Error: This webpage has a redirect loop)

How can I point both to the above folders. I tried the following code.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name xyz.com;
 rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
 return 301 $scheme://www.xyz.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    server_name www.xyz.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    root /var/www/project/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }


    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
            expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ \.(?:css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
            gzip_vary on;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
   }

   location /blog {
        root /var/www/blog;
   }

   location ~ /blog/.+\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/blog$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What works? What doesn't?

Comment: @gf_ www.xyz.com is working and 
www.xyz.com/blog says "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: Alright..so please put this into your question, so it makes sense and people are actually able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a plus php section in `location /blog`:

```
location /blog {
  alias /var/www/blog;
  location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

And you don't need `location ~ /blog/.+\.php$`.

Comment: I am getting 404 - Not found error. 2016/01/23 18:44:52 [error] 12447#0: *3 open() "/var/www/blog/blog" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 27.51.217.2, server: www$

Comment: Removed /blog from /var/www/blog and now, it gives 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault - I don't check your `/blog` section. You should use `alias` instead of `root`. I think now will fine :)

Comment: Now it's saying, No input file specified.

Comment: 2016/01/23 21:13:17 [error] 20425#0: *214 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/blogx.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream,$

Comment: x.php? Can you update your question with full config?

Comment: I removed this line - fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; and added fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; and it worked. Please edit your answer and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You wrote 127.0.0.1, I thought it's correct :)
But I'm glad on success :)